# How to input a tuple in RGB to hex converter?

Tags: python, hex, rgb

I intended to code a simple RGB to hex color converter but then I had a problem with tuple input. The program looks like this:

```
rgb_val = input('Input RGB values: ')
for val in rgb_val.split(','):
    rgb = tuple(val)
hex_color = '#' + ''.join([f'{channel:02x}' for channel in rgb])
print(f'Convert {rgb} to {hex_color}
```

The error is in line 4 and VSCode stated: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'

:02x is used to convert the RGB values into hexadecimal with 2 figures and pad the number with zeroes if we have fewer than 2 figures. So

1. I don't understand what the problem was with x.
2. Can anyone suggest a way to work with tuple input so I don't run into the above error?

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `rgb = tuple(int(val) for val in rgb_val(split(','))` instead of your loop.

Comment: or `int(channel):02x`. In any case avoid to call such numbers "RGB". RGB is a colour model, but we have many different way to express the numbers of RGB, If one is pedantic, it is "R'G'B'" (note the prime sign: the values are gamma corrected. And we have since a lot of year 10 bit-per-channel displays. And we should uses libraries, or we are doomed to CRT technologies of 1990s, when Microsoft and other defined old sRGB.

Comment: It works! Thank you for the correction and information.

Answer (score 1):

Because "channel" is a string type.You need to transfer to integer type.